# What is the substitute of posix operator of Redshift in SparkSQL?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am executing following Redshift SQL command using POSIX operator (~) for pattern matching (It returns true if there is 9 consecutive digit anywhere in the string, else false)

```
select '123456789' ~ '\\d{9}' as val;  --TRUE
```

```
select 'abcd123456789' ~ '\\d{9}' as val;  --TRUE
```

```
select '123456789ab' ~ '\\d{9}' as val; --TRUE
```

How do I do some same pattern matching in SparkSQL?

Answer (score 0):

I believe `rlike` should do the trick:

```py
spark.sql("""SELECT '123456789' rlike '\\\d{9}' as val""").show()
```

```py
spark.sql("""SELECT 'ab123456789' rlike '\\\d{9}' as val""").show()
```

```py
spark.sql("""SELECT '123456789abcd' rlike '\\\d{9}' as val""").show()
```

All result in:

```
+----+
| val|
+----+
|true|
+----+
```

And:

```py
spark.sql("""SELECT '12345678abcd' rlike '\\\d{9}' as val""").show()
```

Results in:

```
+-----+
|  val|
+-----+
|false|
+-----+
```

Comment: If I use rlike, it's showing me FALSE as output. Its not working to match pattern from anywhere in the string !

Comment: @AWSGeekCoder What is your version of Spark? It works for me: https://databricks-prod-cloudfront.cloud.databricks.com/public/4027ec902e239c93eaaa8714f173bcfc/6368096072434975/1396162212387029/2704124371309501/latest.html

Comment: I am using Python 3 and Spark 2.4 version.

Comment: Okay one more thing, I have used 123456789 to show as an example. This value is not fixed and it can be any random 9 digit number. That's why I was trying to use '\\d{9}'.

Comment: @AWSGeekCoder check out the updated version. Apparently I had different regex escaping rules.